# How can I dynamically build the element ID for my jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to reduce this code by using a loop. How can I do that?

```
$("#whiteJenisPembayaran1").live('focus', function() {
    $("#whiteJenisPembayaran1").typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
$("#whiteJenisPembayaran2").live('focus', function() {   
    $("#whiteJenisPembayaran2").typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
$("#whiteJenisPembayaran3").live('focus', function() {
    $("#whiteJenisPembayaran3").typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
```

Comment: dynamic how? just the number at the end? `var num = whatever; $("#whiteJenisPembayaran" + num)` ought to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the HTML? If yes, the best way is setting **class** attribute for these elements.
That way you can do this:

HTML:

```
<div class="whiteJenisPembayaran" id="whiteJenisPembayaran1"></div>
<div class="whiteJenisPembayaran" id="whiteJenisPembayaran2"></div>
<div class="whiteJenisPembayaran" id="whiteJenisPembayaran3"></div>
<div class="whiteJenisPembayaran" id="whiteJenisPembayaran4"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".whiteJenisPembayaran").live('focus', function() {
    $(this).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
```

Comment: Almost. You probably want `$(this)` in the inner function body, otherwise you're applying `.typeahead` to _every_ match wheneven focus is given to _any_ match.

Comment: Really, I did not pay attention. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Now this is excellent :)

Comment: How nice! Please, if this is the solution to your question, mark my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#whiteJenisPembayaran1, #whiteJenisPembayaran2, #whiteJenisPembayaran3").live('focus', function() {
    $(this).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
```

or more "correct" way nowadays:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#whiteJenisPembayaran1, #whiteJenisPembayaran2, #whiteJenisPembayaran3', function() {
    $(this).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
```

Comment: Great but the OP could probably use an explanation.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: if he asks (I highly doubt) - I will explain something particular

Comment: You're missing my point.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: perhaps. What actually have I missed?

Comment: Stack Overflow answers are best when they _describe_ and _explain_, providing _insight_ and _understanding_ rather than merely dumping code... You have enough rep to know how harmful spoonfeeding language newcomers can be!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: yeah, probably I was too laconic here (but I bet OP won't return to this question and probably to SO ever;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function bindListener(index) {
    var key = '#whiteJenisPembayaran' + index;
    $(key).live('focus', function() {
        $(key).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
    });
}

var n = 5; // your max
for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    bindListener(index);
}
```

Done this way to prevent the closure issue with binding events inside loops.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the attribute selector [id^=string] that will select everything with an ID that begin with the string.

```
$("[id^=whiteJenisPembayaran]").live('focus', function() {
    $(this).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
});
```

Comment: Great but the OP could probably use an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of all the ids like this:

```
ids = [ '#whiteJenisPembayaran1', '#whiteJenisPembayaran2', '#whiteJenisPembayaran3' ];

for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    $(ids[i]).live('focus', function() {
        $(ids[i]).typeahead(typeaheadConfig);
    });
}
```